# Add an id value for a canvas element in jquery

Tags: jquery, canvas

How I dynamically add an `id` value for a canvas object in jQuery?

HTML

```
<div id="obj">
    <canvas></canvas>
    <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

How do I change the second canvas object value with `somename`?

Expected result:

```
<canvas id="somename"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$()` function returns an array of matching DOM elements so you can just assign to the `id` property of the second element:

```
$('#obj canvas')[1].id = 'somename';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#obj canvas").slice(1).attr("id","somename");
```

Comment: @Sullan it should (although I'd recommend `.eq()` instead of `.slice()` if you really only want the second and there might be more than two); you'll need to provide a full test case.

Comment: Yep, I should have used an ending index on slice or eq.