# .attr issue with prepend

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have got an issue with `.attr` while trying to set `id` to a prepend. I am doing this so I can control the prepend with commands such as show or hide or animate.

```
$("#1").prepend("<canvas></canvas>").attr('id', 'circle1');
$("#circle1").animate({left: '50%', top: '50%'}, 2000);
```

I use Dreamweaver to code, and when i try to find an element with the id  circle 1 it doesn't find anything and the animation does not work.

I have never used .attr before so can someone please show me where i went wrong

Comment: you can try it like here shown http://stackoverflow.com/a/4977061/3917754

Comment: Doesn't look like a problem with the attr. https://jsfiddle.net/jd53mo13/

Comment: You can see the DOM element length as 1 in the console.

Comment: rahul I'm sorry i am not very good with doms what does that mean